# Virtualenv venv fails with the following error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I'm new to Python development and I'm trying to instal virtualenv in my project directory.

However I have the following error:

```
Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools

  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 347, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 549, in install
      **kwargs
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 963, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 234, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
    File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-6.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 212, in clobber
      shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
      with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py'

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 825, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 993, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 961, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 903, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/alexandrurada...oard/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip failed with error code 2
```

I installed pip with

> easy_install pip

Then I installed virtualenv with

> pip install virtualenv

Without any errors. However I'm still getting this. I didn't want to try it with sudo. Should I?

UPDATE: I installed them with sudo, and I got rid of this error. However another one when trying to install something with pip:

```
air:dashboard alexandrurada$ pip install flask
```

-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: "path_here": bad interpreter: No such file or directory

UPDATE 2: The earlier error was because of a space inside a directory name. Looks like path doesn't work with such names.

Anyway, the error I'm getting now is

```
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip
```

I checked my /usr/local/bin/pip and the file exists.

Comment: Do you have needed privileges? You may need to run `sudo your_cmd`

Answer (score 15):

You need `sudo pip install virtualenv` to install `virtualenv` globally. When setting up your virtualenvs make sure you **don't** use sudo and that you **activate** your virtualenv before trying to install.

`[Errno 13] Permission denied:` means you don't have write permissions.

Comment: You save my day !

Comment: Win10 PowerShell `pip install virtualenv` as admin

Answer (score 4):

Install a newer version of pip and avoid using easy_install.

Download pip from: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py

and then run Python on it:

```
$ python get-pip.py
```

If you want to install `pip` to the global path, you likely want to run that last command with sudo.  Without using sudo, `pip` will get installed for use with whatever Python interpreter is in your path.

From here, you can install virtualenv with pip:

```
$ pip install virtualenv
```

From your responses, it seems like you'd be best served by getting your system in a known state: Download that file, then run `sudo python get-pip.py` so you're running with a known-working pip install.

Comment: I did this and after activating venv, I get global pip path using which pip (which python shows the local one)

Comment: @AlexandruRada What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to start my first project in python. I read about virtualenv and I want it installed. However, even with global pip directory I get an error: -bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: No such file or directory when running for example pip install flask

Comment: Ah, alright then.  You likely want to run my instructions with sudo.  Download that file, then run `sudo python get-pip.py` and you should be in better shape.

Comment: I did this and I manage to fix the error with no such file (it was a space in a directory name and seems that was the issue).   Now, every pip install I'm trying shows me: File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: No module named pip

Comment: @AlexandruRada if you were in a virtualenv, deactivate it and run the install again.